# Starting several codes and stoping after one of them is finish

Tags: bash

So im starting 4 codes at the same time and I want 3 of them to run in a loop until the 4th program finish.

```
loopProgram1 &
loopProgram2 & 
loopProgram3 & 
Program4
```

So I want loopPrograms 1,2 and 3 to execute and then all of them exit once program4 is done. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Already asked and answered here: https://askubuntu.com/q/1012755/10127

Comment: How do you plan to stop your looping programs?  Do you need to send them a signal?  If so, you need to capture the background process IDs (`$!` after each is executed) so you can send them signals.  Even if there's another way to tell them "time's up", you probably still need their PIDs.  And if you're using signals, try to avoid SIGKILL; at least, only use it as a last resort, not the first tool.  What's best depends on the looping programs — SIGHUP or SIGTERM are probably good.

Comment: The looping programs themselves are irrelevant, their job is to create a load while the 4th program is runing. The idea would be that once this forth program is over they would stop. Sending a signal to those programs in order to stop them once the forth program is over is also one of the possibilities

Answer (score 0):

Here is one in bash that takes care of the background processes too if you should kill the main script. First the looper:

```
$ cat loopProgram 
while true             # loops forever echoing its parameter number set in main
do 
  echo $1
  sleep 1
done
```

and the main:

```
$ cat main.bash 
function finish {
    kill %1 %2 %3
}
trap finish EXIT

bash loopProgram 1 &
bash loopProgram 2 &
bash loopProgram 3 &
sleep 3               # this mimics your Program4
```

Run it:

```
$ bash main.bash
2
1
3
1
2
3
2
1
3
$
```

Since my loopers loop forever, if you'd leave the `kill` in the bottom of `main.bash` after the `sleep` and ^C'ing it would leave the loopers running in the background.

(I got the influensa, I hope the example is clear. I probably forget it after the next nap.)